# Как из адаптера списка удалить элемент массива который висит в активити android?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть список основанный на кастомном recyclerView со своей разметкой. Вот разметка одного элемента:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_attachment"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_attach" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

вот адаптер:

```
public class AttachedFileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttachedFileAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    //vars
    private ArrayList<String> mNames;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mImageUrls;
    private Context mContext;


    public AttachedFileAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> imageUrls) {
        mNames = names;
        mImageUrls = imageUrls;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.attached_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                holder.deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });

        holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.w("MY_TAG", "attachment_deleted");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageUrls.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView image;
        TextView name;
        Button deleteBtn;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            deleteBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_attachment);
        }
    }
}
```

все работает почти как нужно, но мне необходимо удалять элемент полностью из массива который находится в активити. Сам массив в формате Json и там находятся данные касательно прикрепленных к письму файлов в формате base64. Я пробовал сделать что-то типа notifyDataSetChanged() но из адаптера такое сделать невозможно. Вот что у меня добавляется в список:

```
private void getImages() {

        filePreview.clear();
        mNames.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

            JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".txt")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_txt);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".zip")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_zip);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".html")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_html);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".pdf")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_pdf);
            }
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).endsWith(".doc")) {
                filePreview.add(R.drawable.ic_doc);
            }


            mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
        }

        initRecyclerView();

    }
```

я не могу понять как достучаться из адаптера до этого массива. Надеюсь проблема решаема и решение лежит на поверхности, но я не смог его найти.

Comment: Что ж Вам так нравится перелопачивать одни и те же данные из одной коллекции в другую?!... Естественно потом встаёт вопрос: "А как же теперь их связать и синхронизировать действия над ними?" - скажем дружно: "Нафиг нужно!" Передайте в адаптер непосредственно Ваш массив и берите данные непосредственно из него и вопрос _как достучаться к нему из адаптера?_ отпал сам по себе. P.S. А что бы было удобнее этим пользоваться замените в принципе этот массив на нормальную коллекцию `POJO (англ. - Старый Добрый Java Объект)`, раз уж всё равно используете `Gson` и `Retrofit`.

Comment: @woesss, то есть мой ответ не очень хорош я так понимаю? как тогда передавать массив в адаптер и потом его обновлять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное что мне пришло в голову, возможно решение не очень правильное, но оно работает. В классе активити я создал статический метод, который удаляет элемент:

```
 public static void deleteAttachment(String name) {
        Log.w("MY_TAG", name);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).equals(name)) {
                array.remove(object); 
                Log.w("MY_TAG", "success");
            }
        }
    }
```

и его я вызываю из адаптера для удаления элемента. Осталось только добавить обновление списка сразу, и будет все работать. Вот как я вызываю этот метод:

```
holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myClass.deleteAttachment(mNames.get(position));
                Log.w("MY_TAG", "attachment_deleted");
            }
        });
```

возможно способ очень громоздкий и будет иногда работать не очень правильно, если у кого-то будут идеи как улучшить мой способ или предложат свой, я буду очень рад ознакомится с вашими ответами.

### Способ №2

у меня есть синглтон, в который я выгружаю массив с данными по файлам, я прислушался к комментарию и подумал что можно все делать в пределах адаптера. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
 holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                JsonArray array = MySingleton.getInstance().getArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                    JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).equals(mNames.get(position))) {
                        array.remove(object);
                        MySingleton.getInstance().setArray(array);
                        Log.w("MY_TAG", "success");
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                //WriteResponseMess.deleteAttachment(mNames.get(position));
                Log.w("MY_TAG", "attachment_deleted");
            }
        });
```

но для обновления самого списка по-моему придется все-таки использовать функцию в классе, чтобы список обновлялся при удалении элемента. Опять таки, если у кого-то будут замечания, то я с радостью с ними ознакомлюсь, для усовершенствования моего кода.

Answer (score 0):

В адаптере удалите желаемый элемент из списка и напишите this.notifyDataSetChanged();